# Java Inserting into database adds new data and it replaces the first row

Tags: java, sql

This is the code for my button, which inserts the data that has been changed in the text boxes of the GUI, once it is pressed.

I have been getting an issue where it adds a new row of data when I press insert, but it also replaces the first row in the table, so I end up having the first and last row equal in all aspects.

May you please help me? It be appreciated.

```
private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    Tblstudents stud = new Tblstudents();

    int row = jTable1.getRowCount();
    row++;

    stud.setStudentid(row);

    stud.setFirstname(jTextField2.getText());
    stud.setSurname(jTextField3.getText());
    String BirthD = dateD.getText();




    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyy-MM-dd");

    try
    {
        Date date = null;
        date = sdf1.parse(BirthD);
        stud.setBirthdate(date);
    } catch (ParseException ex)
    {}
    stud.setGrade(jTextField4.getText());
    stud.setHouseid (Integer.parseInt(jTextField6.getText()));

    StudentHousePUEntityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    StudentHousePUEntityManager.persist(stud);

    StudentHousePUEntityManager.getTransaction().commit();





    tblstudentsList.clear();
    tblstudentsList.addAll(tblstudentsQuery.getResultList());
}
```

Comment: try to change the following: tblstudentsList.clear();
    tblstudentsList.addAll(tblstudentsQuery.getResultList());  to tblstudentsList.add(stud)

Comment: This helped but now it adds a new row as well as replace whichever row I am currently viewing...what a pain, thanks for your reply btw!